# ARM - Invalid Immediate operand value

Tags: arm

The question is to store 12 to R1 and 27 to R2 then subtract R2 with R1 and store the result into the memory address 0x4000. Lastly, store R1 into 0x4004 and R2 into 0x4008 , but I got Invalid immediate Operand Value on MOV R5, #0x4004 and R6, #0x4008.

```
    MOV     R2, #27
    SUB     R3, R2, R1
    MOV     R4, #0x4000
    STR     R3, [R4]
    MOV     R5, #0x4004
    MOV     R6, #0x4008
    STR     R1, [R5]
    STR     R2, [R6]
```

Comment: which instructionset/architecture. arm or thumb and which version?

Comment: what part of the arm instruction set documentation do you not understand?  please post what part you do not understand.

Answer (score 1):

```
MOV     R2, #27
SUB     R3, R2, R1
MOV     R4, #0x4000
STR     R3, [R4, #0]
STR     R1, [R4, #4]
STR     R2, [R4, #8]
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://azeria-labs.com/memory-instructions-load-and-store-part-4/) tutorial, it looks like intermediate values in 32-bit ARM are restricted to "neat" numbers which can be represented as a byte value shifted by some even integer. A quick check of `0x4000` yields `0b100000000000000` which is could be represented by `0x1` shifted left `0d14` times. Your values `0x4004` and `0x4008` don't seem to fall under this category: `0x4004` is `0b100000000000100` and `0x4008` is `0b100000000001000`.

Since those specific values seem important, you could try adding to the value in `R4` and saving those values to `R5` and `R6`.

```
    MOV     R2, #27
    SUB     R3, R2, R1
    MOV     R4, #0x4000
    STR     R3, [R4]
    ADD     R5, R4, #0x4
    ADD     R6, R4, #0x8
    STR     R1, [R5]
    STR     R2, [R6]
```

If you'd like more information, you can check out ARM's own documentation on immediate values [here](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0406/cb/Application-Level-Architecture/ARM-Instruction-Set-Encoding/Data-processing-and-miscellaneous-instructions/Modified-immediate-constants-in-ARM-instructions?lang=en). Just make sure to check that the version of the ISA you're using is the same as the one in the documentation. In the future, try to give as much detail as possible about your environment, since there are many versions of the ARM ISA (for example, the 16-bit thumb version is very different compared to the 32 or 64 bit versions).